# XSD element type won't terminate with matching end-tag

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm receiving an error message for the XSD code - "The element type "element" must be terminated by the matching end-tag /element"..This shows on line /all.. This is only happening to one element type and not the others which I don't understand

```html
<?xml version = "1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsd = "http://wwww.w3.org/2001/XMLSCHEMA"
    xmlns:nutrition = "http://wwww.grandmascookies.com/nutrition"
    targetNamespace = "http://www.grandmascookies.com/nutrition">

    <simpleType name = "amount"> <restriction base = "int"/> </simpleType>
    <simpleType name = "unit"> <restriction base = "string"/> </simpleType>
  
    <complexType name = "nutritionFact">
        <all>
            <element name = "amount" type = "nutrition:amount"/> 
            <element name = "unit" type = "nutrition:unit"/> 
        </all>
    </complexType>
    
    <complexType name = "productType">
        <all>
            <element name = "product" type = "string"> 
            <element name = "servingsize" type = "nutrition:nutritionFact"/>
            <element name = "calories" type = "nutrition:nutritionFact"/>
            <element name = "caloriesFat" type = "nutrition:nutritionFact"/>
            <element name = "gramsFat" type = "nutrition:nutritionFact"/>
            <element name = "saturatedFat" type = "nutrition:nutritionFact"/>
            <element name = "mgCholestral" type = "nutrition:nutritionFact"/>
            <element name = "mgSodium" type = "nutrition:nutritionFact"/>
            <element name = "totalCarbs" type = "nutrition:nutritionFact"/>
            <element name = "fiber" type = "nutrition:nutritionFact"/>
            <element name = "sugar" type = "nutrition:nutritionFact"/>
            <element name = "protein" type = "nutrition:nutritionFact"/>
        </all>
    </complexType>
    
    <xsd:complexType name = "productType1">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name = "item" type = "nutrition:productType"/> 
            <xsd:element name = "items" type = "nutrition:productType1"/>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<element name = "product" type = "string">
```

to

```
<element name = "product" type = "string"/>
                                         ^
```

to eliminate the error.

The reason the error is reported upon closure of `all` is that until that point, it's still possible for the unclosed `element` to be closed such that the XML could be well-formed.  Once the `all` is closed, however, it's clear that well-formedness is impossible.